# Move specific character in sed to the beginnning

Tags: sed

I would like to process a file that contains a specific character in the middle of some words and move it to the beginning of that word. It could also appear at the beginning of a word, but in that case, it should remain in the original position. The special character is ~. I mean:

Original File:

```
This is a sentence with the cha~racter in the middle of a word.
This is a sentence with the ~character at the beginning of a word.
This is a sentence without the character.
```

Expected result:

```
This is a sentence with the ~character in the middle of a word.
This is a sentence with the ~character at the begining of a word.
This is a sentence without the character.
```

Can this be done with a sed script?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed 's/\b\(\w\+\)~\(\w\+\)\b/~\1\2/g' <<< 'This is a sentence with the cha~racter in the middle of a word.
> This is a sentence with the ~character at the beggining of a word.
> This is a sentence without the character.'
This is a sentence with the ~character in the middle of a word.
This is a sentence with the ~character at the beggining of a word.
This is a sentence without the character.
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/\<\([^~][^ ~]*\)~/~\1/g' file
This is a sentence with the ~character in the middle of a word.
This is a sentence with the ~character at the beggining of a word.
This is a sentence without the character.
```